# Is there a replacement for .NET Core in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net-core

I tried to create a VB .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019.  It wasn't installed so I ran the installation again.  It was there to install but states it is out of support. I am trying to make use of its built in functionality for Self-Contained deployments but I see a number of questions on problems with .Net Core and VS 2019, so wondered if there was now an alternative or update for that functionality.  Many thanks.

Comment: .NET 8 is the current and most recent version of the .NET Core lineage - and it's **definitely NOT** out of support...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The 2019 installer seems to list the .net core v3 as a stand alone download.  Whereas searching for .net core v8 downloads, seems to be shown as only being with .net 8.  Must they be installed together?

Comment: Right - VS 2019 only supports up to .NET 7 - for .NET 8, you'll need VS 2022. But unless you actually *have* any .NET Core 3.1 code that you need to work with, no, there's no need to "install both" - just the latest version (.NET 7 for VS 2019, or .NET 8 for VS 2022) will be sufficient